# xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65 FacebookConnectPlugin.m

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic4, facebook-authentication

I've created an Ionic 4 app with Facebook login. It works great on Android but when I attempt to build on the iOS platform I get the following error:

> x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (1
>   failure) xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65 [ERROR] An error
>   occurred while running subprocess cordova.

I get that error with

```
sudo ionic cordova build ios -allowProvisioningUpdates
```

If I then open the app in Xcode and attempt to build I get the following error:

> /Users/anonymous/Development/Mundo1.5/platforms/ios/Buddy
>   Pass/Plugins/cordova-plugin-facebook4/FacebookConnectPlugin.h:13:9:
>   'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found

Comment: hi, have you solve the issue?

Comment: Not really.  I had to remove everything and start over.